# Board to board connections

Tags: prototyping

I am looking for connecters to connect two PCB boards together for prototyping. Can anyone recommend any models in particular.

Features I am looking for are decent price available from some where like Farnell or RS Components in Australia
3 wire mainly doesn't need speacilized tools to make the connects standard pin spacing for  prototyping board
Also up to 10+ connections

I have looked my self but there is hundreds of models and it's hard to work out how they make there connects

Anyone recommend any models that they use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [these](http://www.rapidonline.com/Cables-Connectors/Connectors-Multipole/PCB-Interconnect/Single-row-sockets/76075) with standard headers for stacking boards. I buy the longer ones and cut them to size.

For wire connections between boards I use [these](http://www.rapidonline.com/Cables-Connectors/Connectors-Multipole/PCB-Interconnect/Crimp-2.54mm-PCB-connection-system/63798) connectors with [these](http://www.rapidonline.com/Cables-Connectors/Connectors-Multipole/PCB-Interconnect/2.54mm-Crimp-terminal/63799) terminals and [these](http://www.rapidonline.com/Cables-Connectors/Connectors-Multipole/PCB-Interconnect/Crimp-2.54mm-PCB-connection-system/63798) housings. The [crimp tool](http://www.rapidonline.com/Tools-Fasteners-Production-Equipment/Hand-Tools/Tacking-Crimping/Crimping-tool-for-PCB-connectors/30535) is quite cheap.

Comment: All links are dead.  Might want to include model numbers and pictures next time.

Answer (score 3):

I use these, I had the same issue looking for PCB connectors, then I found these and they work great. [image: Female wire connectors]
I bought them from adafruit - [product page](http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=33&products_id=266)

Comment: Was after something I could make my self at what ever length

Answer (score 0):

I use standard 0.1" pitch headers and then I connect everything via wire-wrap. That way I can modify if I make a mistake or if I want to change it up.

I typically connect one end to the board itself and then the other to some long pinned breakaway headers. That way I can remove the connections from a development board and plug into a completely different system in seconds.

[image: Wire Wrap Prototyping]

This does require you to purchase wire-wrap wire, a decent stripping tool, and a wire wrapping tool. If you look on eBay they're dirt cheap compared to what you can get them for new from Digikey (or the like)

I wrote an article and made a video on wire wrap for prototyping on [Circuit Dojo](https://www.circuitdojo.org/fundamentals/#wire-wrap). Feel free to check it out.

Answer (score -3):

Uh, what's wrong with using bog standard 0.1" headers? There's tons of models because EVERYBODY uses them and they are a commodity product.

Comment: This is exactly why she's asking: "... but there are hundreds of models..."

Comment: I had the same issue looking for them. digikey, newark or any of the suppliers have a lot of the connectors but sorting them out and finding the correct one for you application is tough.

Comment: Leon's comment are the ones I will use

Comment: Oh and I am a Male not that it matters much